# WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, None) for input KerasTensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reshape, word-embedding

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, None) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.float32, name='embedding_2_input'), name='embedding_2_input', description="created by layer 'embedding_2_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None,).
```

I'm trying to build a word embedding model but I getting this error.

```
x.shape, y.shape
((385, 2), (385, 149))

model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(len(word_index)+1, 1024))
model.add(LSTM(1024))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1]))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 embedding_2 (Embedding)     (None, None, 1024)        152576    
                                                                 
 lstm_2 (LSTM)               (None, 1024)              8392704   
                                                                 
 dropout_2 (Dropout)         (None, 1024)              0         
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 149)               152725    
                                                                 
 activation_1 (Activation)   (None, 149)               0         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 8,698,005
Trainable params: 8,698,005
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

```
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=64, epochs=40)

model.predict([88], verbose=0)
```

It was working last year, I guess because of the version update.
How can I fix it.

Comment: ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential" (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "lstm" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 1024)
    
    Call arguments received:
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=int64)
      • training=False
      • mask=None

Comment: How does x look? Can you show one example of your `x` and `y`?

Comment: print(X)
[[  7  88]
 [ 88  26]
 [ 26  12]
 [ 12  27]
 [ 27  19]
 [ 19  89]
 [ 89   4]
 [  4  14]
 [ 14  28]
 [ 28   5]
 [  5  90]
 [ 90   3]
 [  3  29]
 [ 29  30] ...]

Comment: print(y)

[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]